# Use programming to set touch input on android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, touch, android-sdk-tools

I want to use programming to mimic a "touch" on a position (x, y) on the screen.

I saw [this](http://www.pocketmagic.net/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/) link, but it only teaches you how to inject characters.

I want to inject a touch at position (x, y)

How do I do this using Android SDK (which is java)?

Answer (score 4):

You can "fake" a touch event like this:

```
MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, action, x, y, metaState);
view.onTouchEvent(event);
```

**API Docs**:

> Create a new MotionEvent, filling in a
>   subset of the basic motion values.
>   Those not specified here are: device
>   id (always 0), pressure and size
>   (always 1), x and y precision (always
>   1), and edgeFlags (always 0).

**Parameters**:

- `downTime` The time (in ms) when the
  user originally pressed down to start
  a stream of position events. This
  must be obtained from
  SystemClock.uptimeMillis().
- `eventTime` The the time (in ms) when
  this specific event was generated.
  This must be obtained from
  `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`.
- `action` The kind of action being
  performed -- one of either
  `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`,
  `ACTION_UP`, or `ACTION_CANCEL`.
- `x` The X coordinate of this event.
- `y` The Y coordinate of this event.
- `metaState` The state of any meta /
  modifier keys that were in effect
  when the event was generated.

[Link to API Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#obtain(long,%20long,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int))

Comment: +1 Well I believe you are right, but I wasn't able to make it work. See [my new topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294349/motionevent-obtain-not-working-as-on-screen-tapper)

Answer (score 0):

That would be [Monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) to do the job